# How do I move a PostgreSQL tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is there a way to physically move a PostgreSQL 9.3 tablespace from `/old/dir` to `/new/dir`? I'd like to just `mv` the directory and tell PostgreSQL that the tablespace is now located at `/new/dir`. Looks like `ALTER TABLESPACE` only lets you rename.

I'd like to avoid creating a new tablespace and moving the database to it. I assume that would be a slow copy process that requires a lot of time and disk space. I also want to avoid symlinking `/old/dir` to `/new/dir`.

Comment: move /old/dir to veryold/dir , mount new/dir to old/dir , copy data from ver_old dir to old/dir ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume that your tablespace name is `tblspc`.

1. Get Oid of your tablespace

```
test=# SELECT oid,spcname FROM pg_tablespace WHERE spcname = 'tblspc';
  oid  | spcname 
-------+---------
 24580 | tblspc
(1 row)
```

2. Stop postgres

```
$ pg_ctl -D $PGDATA stop
```

3. Move directory from old one to new one

```
$ mv /old/dir /new/dir
```

or

```
$ cp -r /old/dir /new/dir
$ rm -rf /old/dir
```

4. Change tablespace's link to new directory

```
$ cd $PGDATA/pg_tblspc
$ rm 24580
$ ln -s /new/dir 24580
```

6. Start postgres

```
$ pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start
```

---

Then, you can see the tablespace's directory has changed.

```
test=# SELECT pg_tablespace_location(24580);
 pg_tablespace_location
------------------------
 /new/dir
(1 row)
```