# How to move the pg_default tablespace to a different location?

Tags: postgresql

A [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129382/how-do-i-move-a-postgresql-tablespace) contains detailed instructions on how to move a tablespace to a different location. I would like to do something similar with the default tablespace (`pg_default`), but its meta-data is presented differently to other tablespaces.

```
# select spcname
      ,pg_tablespace_location(oid)
from   pg_tablespace;
  spcname   | pg_tablespace_location
------------+-------------------------
 pg_default |
 pg_global  |
```

I work on Linux with the data directory currently at `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main`. But the contents of this folder appear different from a user created tablespace location.

```
# SHOW data_directory;
       data_directory
-----------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/14/main
```

How can the default tablespace be moved to a different location? If that is even possible.